# How to show the data of a tableview cell to another viewcontroller when clicking on that particular cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am totally new in iOS developing. I am building a basic project where I have two view controllers. In one of them I have a tableView, and in another I have a label and a textfield. In tableview I have taken a custom cell and in that I have taken two labels. In that two labels I have assigned two arrays. Now I want to show the datas of that two arrays to the label and textfield of the other view controller. So I want to know what code to write in the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

This is the code I have done.

```
#import "TabViewController.h"

@interface TabViewController ()

@end

@implementation TabViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.peoplenames = @[@"Soumen Da" ,@"Debu Da" ,@"Sandipan Da" ,@"Pradipta Da" ,@"Sandeep Da" ,@"Pran Da" ,@"Amit Da" ,@"Piyali Di" ,@"Niladri Da" ,@"Biswa Da", @"Soumitra Da" ,@"Utpal Da", @"Sandip Da"];

    self.peopleaddress = @[@"Santragachhi" ,@"Kolkata" ,@"Shambazar" ,@"Jadavpur" ,@"Saltlake" ,@"New Town" ,@"Beleghata" ,@"Garia" ,@"Barakpur" ,@"Naihati" ,@"Agarpara" ,@"Sodpur" ,@"Park Street"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];


    UILabel *lbl1 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    lbl1.text = [self.peoplenames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"row===%ld",(long)indexPath.row);

    UILabel *lbl2 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    lbl2.text = [self.peopleaddress objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"row===%ld",(long)indexPath.row);

    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detail" sender:self];

}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [self.peoplenames count];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a segue from table cell to the next view controller and no need to do any thing in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath.`

Use `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` in first view controller with table view and access segue.destinationViewController.label and segue.destinationViewController.label.textField to pass the values to the 2nd view controller.

Comment: Do I need to create another class for the second view controller?

Comment: Yes you need to create

Answer (score 0):

if you want in didSelectRowAtIndexPath do like the following way.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 UIStoryboard *sb=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        DetailViewController *vc=(DetailViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
        vc.label.text =[self.peopleaddress objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
vc. textfield.text =[self.peopleaddress objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
```

Comment: 'Doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'detail''. This error is coming.

Comment: goto DetailViewController in storyboard and goto class inspector of DetailViewController there you can find give 'detail' in StoryBoard id field and then run.

Comment: But first create DetailViewController with  label and textfield.

Comment: have your created allocated textfield and lable ? if still not coming then create one Nsstring object in DetailViewController like Nsstring *str. in the above code just modify vc.str=[self.peopleaddress objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; and place str value in textfiled .

Comment: I did exactly what you have told, but still nothing coming.

Comment: Done with the way you said Arjuna, I was trying with the way sanginadham murali said.